# What is causing angular list redraw and how to mitigate it?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 Angular app with a chat page. It displays up to 50 chat messages and has an input to send a message.

The list of messages is retrieved from Google's Firestore and served to the app as an observable. Here is how I am displaying the messages.

```
<ion-list class="chat-list">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages; let last = last; trackBy: trackByCreated">
            <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
                <img-loader src="{{msg.user?.thumbnail != null ? msg.user?.thumbnail : 'assets/person-icon.svg'}}"></img-loader>
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-label text-wrap>
                <div style="color: gray; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="message-name">{{msg.user?.displayname}}</div>
                    <div class="message-date">{{getDateString(msg.messagedate)}}</div>
                </div>
                <p style="color: black;">{{msg.messagecontent}}</p>
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

This is the `getDateString` method you can see called for every message:

```
getDateString(date: number){
    this.logging("Inside get date string.");

    let d = new Date(date);
    let dn = Date.now();

    //If it's the same day, return just the time string
    if (Math.round(<any>dn/(1000*60*60*24)) == Math.round(<any>d/(1000*60*60*24)))
        return d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');

    return d.toLocaleString('en-US');
}
```

Track by function:

```
trackByCreated(i, msg) {
    return msg.messagedate;
}
```

This issue is, Angular seems to be redrawing the list of messages extremely often, even when there are no new ones to display (The observable isn't transmitting new data according to the subscriber I have logging in page's code.). It redraws every time I scroll the page, type a character in the input, or just click anywhere on the page. Is this normal behavior? The constant calls to the `getDateString` function are destroying performance.

**Edit**: Also, on the initial page load, the data is only transmitted to the page once but the list gets redrawn 20 times. Is that normal behavior?

Below you can see a log of all of the calls. Red represents typing in the input, blue is scrolling, and green is just clicking on the screen.

[image]

Comment: I know I should format the date string before the data is served to the page. I can do that. However, I would still like to know why the list is being redrawn so much.

Comment: Can you add the source code for the `trackByCreated` function.

Comment: @cgTag I added it under the others.